# C: Handling HTTP requests and responses

Tags: c, http

What is the best C library for sending HTTP requests and processing the responses?

Comment: Any comments on [libcurl's competitors](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/competitors.html)?

Answer (score 4):

[libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/) is a good library for this.